# Use sharedPreferences to add values to a string

Tags: java, android

My goal is to save a value to a `string`, and then store the `string` to `sharedPreferences`. Moreover, every time the app generates a new value, I would like to add this `string` to the `string array`, which would increase the length of the `string array` by 1 every time the app is used. I have spent 200+ hours trying to make this work, but I still can't get it to work properly. This is what I have so far:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

Set set = new HashSet();
set.add(EnterText.mynumber);

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(days,Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.putStringSet("strings", set);
        Boolean flag = editor.commit();

        SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("MyPrefs",Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
        Set set=new HashSet();
        set=prefs.getStringSet("strings", null);

    }

}
```

If anyone knows the right method to do this, or how I can fix this code to make it work, I would **greatly** appreciate it.

Thanks for your help

Comment: This is not clear. Do you mean increase the text of the string or do you mean add a new string in an array of strings?

Comment: @Mikael, I would like to add a new string in the array of strings. Sorry for the confusion!

Comment: But you want it the sharefprefs one element per array value?

Comment: Why are you using {} in `getSharedPreferences{days,Context.MODE_PRIVATE};` instead of ()?

Comment: @algui91, Essentially what I'm trying to is keep the old string array in `sharedPreferences`, and when the app runs again, I would like to add the new value (`EnterText.mynumber`) to the old string array. This way, all of the values that the user obtained previously stay saved in the app.

Comment: @algui91, I'm not sure, thanks for the catch, I'll change it and see if it works

Comment: Does your code compile? If not, what errors do you get? If it does, what happens when you run it?

Answer (score 2):

You should use putStringSet instead of putString.

Basically you need to create a set with all of your strings.

```
Set set =new HashSet();
set.add("String 1");
set.add("String 2");
set.add("String 3");
```

Then you can write:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("MyPrefs",
        Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
editor.putStringSet("strings", set);
Boolean flag = editor.commit();
```

To get it back the next time you run the app you can do:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("MyPrefs",
        Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
Set set=new HashSet();
set=prefs.getStringSet("strings", null);
```

Comment: Awesome, just one question: when I am creating a set with all of my strings (in the first part of the code you described), do I replace `"String 1"` with my string `number`?

Comment: yes but drop the brackets from the declaration or even the declaration entirely: `set.add(EnterText.mynumber);`

Comment: hmm.. when I try this I get the errors `Multiple markers at this line
 - Syntax error on token ".", ... expected
 - Syntax error on token "add", Identifier expected after 
  this token`

Comment: I am sorry but your code makes no sense. You need to think about what you are trying to do before you start writing code. At some point your application will need to save strings to SharedPreferences and at another it will retrieve them. This is the several bits of code I gave you. What you wrote create an Activity gets a string, puts it into SharedPreferences and get's it back again. Beyond the fact that you declare `set` twice (causing a crash) it simply makes no sense to do that as you do not need SharedPreferences at all.

Comment: The thing is, even after this app shuts down, I want the strings to be available the next time the app starts up. That's why I need the `sharedPreferences` to get a string, and then feed it back out.

Comment: OK so then you need to do the following: when the user gives you the number you need to: (1) check if it's the first time any number if given. (2) if it is you do the first bit of code, if not the third one. (3) the second bit of code.